# If we "turned universe upside-down" and changed all matter to anti-matter instantly

Tags: cosmology, antimatter

...what would be the immediate consequences?

Or putting it better, if (from big-bang or whathever), the universe were always made of what we call Anti-matter what would it be?

The scientists of this universe would call 'Matter' 'Anti-Matter'.

Will the universe looks like exactly the same? By "looks", I mean the laws of Physics, the constitution of the universe with its superclusters of galaxies containing clusters containing galaxies and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would look very similar, but tiny differences are suspected, see e.g. [this LHC experiment](http://home.web.cern.ch/about/updates/2013/04/lhcb-experiment-observes-new-matter-antimatter-difference).

[Here a list of more antimatter experiments at CERN](http://home.web.cern.ch/topics/antimatter).

See also [CP violation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation) hinting towards tiny differences between matter and antimatter.

Immediate consequence: The CP violation parameter of the [CKM matrix](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2008/reviews/kmmixrpp.pdf) in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix) would be different, because of different quark generation probabilities.

If you also reverse time, you'll get to the [CPT theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry) (Charge, Parity, Time). Matter and antimatter are thought to be symmetric in this sense.

Or to state it with simpler words: Antimatter behaves like matter travelling backward in time.

Comment: `Antimatter behaves like matter travelling backward in time` -  can you please explain more specifically what do you mean by this?